# Almost Disjoint Uncountable Subgroups of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: group-theory, real-numbers

This idea struck me as I was heading to bed last night:  Can we find uncountable subgroups $H,G < \mathbb{R}$ such that $H \cap G = \{0\}$?

The issue I see is that uncountable sets are really big, and necessarily have a limit point.  Then, each of $H$ and $G$ would have to be dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (which isn't a problem in and of itself, since $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}\sqrt{2}$ are disjoint dense subgroups of $\mathbb{R}$).

Obviously the groups in question can't contain an interval, since otherwise they would equal the whole of $\mathbb{R}$.  I was thinking of doing something with the Vitali set $\mathcal{N}$ along these lines:

- Let $\mathcal{N}_1 = \mathcal{N} \cap [0,1/2)$ and $\mathcal{N}_2 = \mathcal{N} \cap (1/2,1]$.
- Investigate $\langle \ \mathcal{N}_1 \ \rangle$ and $\langle \ \mathcal{N}_2 \ \rangle$ and hope really hard that they come out almost disjoint.

But so far that isn't working.  Any ideas?

Maybe it's not possible, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean additive groups ?. $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, of dimension the continuum. So just take the vector subspaces generated by two independent sets of size continuum.

Comment: Ah, yes. I feel so silly now.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Choose a $\mathbb Q$-basis $B = (b_\alpha \mid \alpha \in A)$ of $\mathbb R$. Let $B = B_1 \uplus B_2$. Then $\def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<B_1>_{\mathbb Q} \cap \<B_2>_{\mathbb Q} = \{0\}$, so this also holds for the generated subgroups.

Comment: are those things uncountable?

Comment: Yes, as $\dim_{\mathbb Q}\mathbb R$ is uncountable, $B$ is uncountable. And hence, we can choose $B_1$ and $B_2$ both uncountable.